# Is there a Quicklook debug command in LLDB?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, lldb, quicklook

Let's say I have a `UIImage` that I'm setting for a `UIButton`. I want to look at it in Quicklook. But oh no:

[image]

There's no way for me to quick look debug what the image is.

But I could do something from LLDB to get the image, like `[getAppButton imageForState:0]` (well, I could if it wasn't for the undoManager bit but that's not neither here nor there), but is there a way to quicklook that?

Comment: Can you trigger it through a `lldb` command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure when this was introduced, but in Xcode 6.3.2 you can right click on the left panel in the debug area and choose `Add Expression...`. This pops up a text field where you can put in any arbitrary LLDB expression. After entering it, you can invoke quick look on the expression just like any other local variable in that pane.

[image: Quicklook]

You can also reference variables defined in LLDB, for example if you were to type:

```
(lldb) e UIImage *$img = [button imageForState:0]
```

You can then reference that `$img` as the expression in the left pane.

Comment: Good thing I can change the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent solution. Swift example:
`e let $img = cell.imageView.image`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible. At least I could not find a suitable command in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-command-examples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012917-CH3-SW1).

The only way I can think of, is modifying your code to assign the image in a UIImage variable and quick look that...

Comment: This is a helpful article from NSHipster on Quick Look Debugging which describes possible quick look methods including from the debugger or using breakpoints to quick look inline code (as recommended above) but does not mention any options from the command line unfortunately. http://nshipster.com/quick-look-debugging/

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 5.1, you can now add a method:

```
- (id)debugQuickLookObject
```

to any object and the returned value will be used for QuickLook. So in your case, you could subclass your button, and return your image.

Comment: Sure, but I was hoping to be able to do it somehow from the console.

Comment: The question was not about defining a quicklook but how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do that using chisel's [`visualize`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VafHI.jpg) lldb command. It's very straightforward to set up, and it's a debugger super-power that's particularly handy if you work with images a lot.

Once you've installed [chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel), update your `~/.lldbinit` file and restart XCode. Then create a new breakpoint and add an action that uses the command to inspect an `UIImage`[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VafHI.jpg).

[image: lldb breakpoint settings in XCode]

Under the hood, the new python based lldb command writes the image buffer into a timestamp-based PNG file under `/tmp/xcode_debug_images` and then call system command `open` to use the default app to open up the image.

Keep in mind that `lldb` holds a strong reference to the data. So during your debug session, your app might appear to leak RAM. Remember to turn the breakpoint off when you are done.

Also, if you have a lot of images, you may not want to open them up all in Preview, which will freeze itself with more than 100 images. Comment this line off, and you should be fine:
https://github.com/facebook/chisel/blob/main/commands/FBVisualizationCommands.py#L60

On my M1 mac, the file is installed into `/usr/local/opt/chisel/libexec/commands/FBVisualizationCommands.py`